# How to change AxesHelper x-y-z line width and add arrow point in Three.js

Tags: angular, three.js

I am able create axes using AxesHelper

[image: Achieved]

Now, I want to increase the width of the axes lines and add arrow point,

I am beginner to three.js, Please help me to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 3 instances of [THREE.ArrowHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/ArrowHelper) and build the axes yourself. Here's how you could do the Y-axis:

```js
// Direction: up
var dir = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
dir.normalize();
var origin = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
var length = 1;
var hex = 0x00ff00;

var arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex );
scene.add( arrowHelper );
```

The only thing is that WebGL linewidths greater than 1 are not guaranteed to work, so you might want to [add a cylinder](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry) if you want the stem to have some thickness.

Answer (score 4):

This is a full working example of using ArrowHelper() to make what you're looking for. It uses a second canvas that's locked to the main canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/b97zd1a3/16/

```
var arrowPos = new THREE.Vector3( 0,0,0 );
arrowScene.add( new THREE.ArrowHelper( new THREE.Vector3( 1,0,0 ), arrowPos, 60, 0x7F2020, 20, 10 ) );
arrowScene.add( new THREE.ArrowHelper( new THREE.Vector3( 0,1,0 ), arrowPos, 60, 0x207F20, 20, 10 ) );
arrowScene.add( new THREE.ArrowHelper( new THREE.Vector3( 0,0,1 ), arrowPos, 60, 0x20207F, 20, 10 ) );
```